# Should my windows partitions be contiguous?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, elementaryos

I'm going to dual boot elementary OS with Windows 10. This is how my disk is currently partitioned:

[image: partitions]

I have succeeded in dual booting my previous laptop with the same OS, but my disk wasn't partitioned this way. The Windows-related partitions were on the left, and I had my eOS ones all on the right.

I would like to know the consequences of putting the partitions of another OS in-between the two Windows partitions. I can't risk losing my files especially right now, so I really have to be careful.

Comment: No they don't need to be contiguous. And they can be any order you like.

Comment: The only problem you may face is that there’s no place for the Linux boot partition, which IIRC still needs to be a primary partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in terms of the logic of it, few or no OSes require contiguous partitions; you can intersperse them however you like; **however....**

On a traditional spinning hard disk, head seeks take time, and the longer the distance between partitions, the longer the seeks take. Thus, separating two partitions used by the same OS can degrade performance, since head seek times will increase compared to keeping those partitions close together. The extent of this problem varies depending on the disk hardware, the nature of the partitions, and the size of the gap between them. For instance, if you separate a Linux `/boot` partition from its main root (`/`) partition, you'll likely see little degradation in performance, because the `/boot` partition is seldom accessed once the OS has booted; but if you separate `/home` from root (`/`), you'll likely see more degradation.

I'm less familiar with some of the specialized Windows partitions that have been cropping up lately, and there's less standardization in partition uses in the Windows world than in Linux, so it's hard for me to comment on your proposed layout. In particular, what's on your Windows `C:` and `D:` partitions? Also, what's on those small ~500MB partitions at the start and end of the disk?

You must also keep in mind the fact that partition resizing and moving operations take time and are not risk-free. You might want to accept some small day-to-day performance degradation rather than take the time to move your partitions and risk data loss in doing so. (OTOH, if you've got adequate backups, moving your partitions shouldn't risk actual data loss, and if you don't have adequate backups, you're risking catastrophic data loss every day.)

Note also that these performance issues are irrelevant with SSDs, which store data in chips rather than on a medium with physically-moving parts. On an SSD, performance isn't affected by distance between partitions. There are other performance issues with SSDs, though. Most notably, you should enable [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) in your OSes. Various pages, like [this one,](http://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/storage/12-ssd-tips-to-optimise-your-drive-s-performance-943984) describe other things you can do to improve SSD performance.

Comment: I'm sorry for replying late, but thank you for your reply! My C: partition is where my system files are, and the D: partition is just for my extra files (I just prefer not to put them in one big partition). My disk is partitioned this way because I actually made a mistake when I re-formatted my laptop. I guess I'll just format it again some time in order to fix the order.